# Как изменить картинку в бд delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

Добавляю, удаляю, отображаю картинки в delphi в поле image но из за того, что я использую метод query.insert, а метода query.update судя по всему нет, я не знаю как изменять картинки в уже существующее поле. id для условия беру в editе на форме

[image: [1]]
код добавления картинок с данными, извиняюсь что код картинкой, доступа к тому жесткому диску на котором программа нет, а скрины остались

Comment: Код картинкой, переведите в текст все же. Если доступа к коду нет, то и решение вам не нужно ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. adoquery1.Edit не работает?
2. Как вариант - обновлять отдельным запросом (через ADOCommand, например).